# matlab indices not in range?

Tags: matlab, indexing, indices

I'm trying to write the optimal quantization for IP.
I'm new to matlab and in this code, i'm trying to go over every pixel in every interval of Z, multiply it with it's histogram and sum it , so I can calculate the optimal Q.

problem : `Attempted to access hist(257);index out of bounds because numel(hist)=256.`

```
for i=1:K,

    for j=(Z(i)):Z(i+1),

       sum1=(j)*hist(j+1)+sum1;
       count=count+hist(j+1);

    end
end
```

Comment: The exception is really obvious, you are accessing `hist(257)` which does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that you cannot access `hist(257)` because the array `hist` only has 256 elements in it. Note that `hist` is also a built in function name so you really ought to consider giving your variable a different name.

How to solve:

Think carefully about your code, and what you are trying to achieve. What are `Z`. `hist` and `K`? What is the largest value that `j` can reach (`=Z(i+1)`)? That is the value with which you are indexing `hist`, and apparently `hist` is not that big. What then is the shape of each variable?

Comment: K=2^N; N is the number of bits
In the beggining Z is devided equaly Z=z0:D:zk; z0=0, zk =255 (gray scale). 
The largest value of Z is 255 , and K+1=numel(Z). So I don't understand how does hist reach 257 ?? numel(hist) =256

Comment: It does sound puzzling. When the code stops, what are the values of `i`, `j`, `Z(i+1)`? Is there any other code that you are not showing that changes the value of `Z`?

Comment: solved it, you were correct the problem wasn't in this loop.